# How to Fix Save and Load Play Prefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a settings menu that has the option for a volume, viewdistance, and quality sliders. I want to save the value of those and use them when the player loads into the game. My issue is the quality level and view distance reset while the volume saves properly.

```
private void Start()
    {
        if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("musicVolume"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVolume",1);
            Load();
        }
        else 
        {
            Load();
        }
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("qualityLevel"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityLevel",6);
            Load();
            
        }
        
        else 
        {
            Load();
        }
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("ViewDistance"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("ViewDistance", 10);
            Load();
            Debug.Log("saved viewdistance" + qualityslider.value * 1000);
        }
        else 
        {
            Load();
        }
    }
private void Save()
    {
        
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVolume", volumeslider.value);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityLevel", QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel());
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("ViewDistance", qualityslider.value);
    }
private void Load()
    {
        volumeslider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVolume");
        qualityslider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ViewDistance");
         QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityLevel"));
    }
public void ChangeVolume ()
     
    {
        Save();
        AudioListener.volume = volumeslider.value;

    }
public void ChangeViewDistance()
{
    Save();
    Camera.main.farClipPlane  = viewDistanceSlider.value * 1000;

}
 public void ChangeQuality(float level)
 {
    //level = qualityslider.value;
      
           
           // QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(level, false);
           
           switch((float)level)
      {

         case 0:
     QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(0); // For lowest quality
     break;
     case 1:
     QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(1); // For lowest quality
     break;
     case 2:
     QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(2); // For lowest quality
     break;
     case 3:
     QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(3); // For lowest quality
     break;
     case 4:
     QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(4); // For lowest quality
     break;
     case 5:
     QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(5); // For lowest quality
     break;
     case 6:
     QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(6); // For lowest quality
     break;
      }
       
}
```

This is my first time trying save and load with player prefs in unity. I recieve no errors and can't find anything online. The volume saves but the view distance and quality do not.

[image: UI]

[image: UI]

[image: ChangeQuality]

[image: Change View Distance]
[image: Change Volume]

Comment: Why do you always `Save` and `Load` all values together but for each individual settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main mistake is

```
qualityslider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ViewDistance");
```

That's the wrong slider! ;)

---

In general you `Load` the values into the sliders .. but you do not apply them to the actual systems!

Before coming to that some other comments.

In the `ChangeQuality` you are using a `switch` on a `float` value.

For a `float` it is mostly unlikely that they ever match an exact integer value! E.g. `0.5 + 0.5` might instead of the expected `1` rather be `1.0000001` or `0.99999999` in which case it won't enter the expected `case`.

You would probably rather do something like e.g.

```
var level = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.RoundToInt(value), 0, 6);
QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(level);
```

Besides that as mentioned before you are not calling `Save` within that method.

In general your entire `Start` method could be simplified a lot by simply providing fallback/default values like

```
private void Start ()
{
    Load();
}

private void Load()
{
    var volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVolume", 1);
    var distance = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ViewDistance", 10);
     var quality= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityLevel", 6);

    // ... See below 
}
```

Then later on I would always only actually set the value that changed instead of everytime polling and saving them all.

Therefore you should use parameterized callbacks and do

```
public void ChangeVolume (float value)   
{
    AudioListener.volume = volumeslider.value;
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVolume", value);
}

public void ChangeViewDistance(float value)
{
    Camera.main.farClipPlane  = viewDistanceSlider.value * 1000;
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("ViewDistance", value);
}

public void ChangeQuality(float value)
{
    var level = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.RoundToInt(value), 0, 7);
    QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(level);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityLevel", level));
}
```

And then finally coming back to the very first point:

Actually call all those once after loading!

```
private void Load()
{
    var volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVolume", 1);
    ChangeVolume(Volume);
    var quality =  PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityLevel", 6);
    ChangeQuality(quality);
    var distance = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("ViewDistance", 10);
    ChangeViewDistance(distance);
}
```

Comment: I followed your directions however I'm stuck at the same issue. I use a debug.log to print the current quality level in the update function. When I change the slider it works perfectly. However, when I exit runtime and then go back in the quality resets to 5 and the slider resets to max. The same thing happens for the view distance and audio. I double checked that the script is selected in the inspector window for the slider and all works as intended but it doesn't save or load

Comment: I manged to get the view distance and volume to work by adding 'volumeslider.value = volume;' under the Load function. But I can't get it to work for the quality.

Comment: I found the mistake, you GetFloat for the quality when the value is an Int

Comment: @Coding_Goose oh snap sorry, copy paste mistake on my side ^^ glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your ChangeVolume() function calls Save() but your ChangeQuality() function does not.

Comment: I fixed it but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly,

You check if the key exists and if you don't set the value, you can just use `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("YourKey", DefaultValue)` because when the player will need a different value they'll just change it in the settings and the new value will be read.

Secondly, you don't need to always update the preferences, only when they are changed, i. e. you change volume and save only volume, it's easier to write and read.

Thirdly, in `ChangeQuality(float level)` you can just do `QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(level)` and use `Mathf.Clamp(level, 0, 6)` if you wanna restirct with the range from 0 to 6.

After doing that check if you call `ChangeViewDistance()` and `ChangeQuality()`, that's probably the whole cause of the problem.

Comment: sorry but im confused. I check if player.prefs has a key and if it does not I set it to a value. Second, how do I only update the preference when they are changed.  The only time the function ChangeViewDistance() and ChangeQuality() is called is when the slider is moved.

Comment: You don't need to check if a key exists, just read and pass a default value as the second parameter. To update the changed preference you can call an event when the value of an input field is changed, for example. I would tell more or another way if I knew how you implemented the settings page.

Edited: you can call a method to set the new value when the slider's value has changed. Take a look at the bottom of your slider component, it has OnValueChanged box

Comment: i added some pictures showing how the setting page is used

Comment: I added another answer to make more clear

Answer (score 0):

To save the changed value of a slider to PlayerPrefs your public method must look like that

```
public void ChangeQuality(System.Single value) => PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("qualityLevel", Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, 6));
```

You need to use `System.Single` because it will help Unity automatically pass the new value, so you can save it.

Your method in the list must be under 'Dynamic float' label

[image]

Comment: would this replace the changequality void because I already select dynamic float when assigning it to the slider. Also if are you able to show me how to use the mathfclamp. (sorry for asking for so much but this is all very new to me)

Comment: No problem, that's the whole idea of StackOverflow. I edited the answer, Mathf.Clamp() isn't really necessary here, because your slider has min of 0 and max of 6

Comment: can u show me what the code would look like for changing the quality because I'm confused on what to replace

Comment: pardon me, I made a mistake in the code. Now it looks like the code that you can copy and paste in stead of your ChangeQuality method

Comment: Would I put   QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(3);  inside the void?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry about that, you can

Comment: But the data won't be save to the PlayerPrefs if you don't have that code inside SetQualityLevel

Comment: public void ChangeQuality()
 {
    QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel((System.Single value) => PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("qualityLevel", Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, 6)));
 }

Comment: this give me the error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: So that's how you are new to Unity and C#, copy this code
public void ChangeQuality(System.Single value) { QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(level); PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("qualityLevel", value); } and this method must be called when the slider value is changed

Comment: I really do apologize but it says the name level doesn't exist in the current context. If I change "value" to "level" it says cannot convert float to int. Again I'm really sorry for dragging this out.

Comment: yeah, replace 'level' with 'value' and cast it to int by writing '(int)value'

Comment: Now I go into runtime change the value of the quality and exit runtime, then go back in the value of the slider resets. I think it may be a problem with the save, load, or start either not saving it or resetting the value everytime. It seems to work fine with the audio which is why I am so confused

Comment: `You need to use System.Single` .. no .. you can and should but you can also just stick to fetching it from the `slider.value` as well .. in general stick to one answer except you are suggesting a complete alternative solution maybe ... `(int)value` is also a bit risky.. you should probably rather use `Mathf.RoundToInt(value)` .. otherwise e.g. `0.99999999999999` would unexpectedly return `0`

Comment: But the slider uses whole numbers, in reality it won't return value 0.9(9)